# How to get process to set it's affinity?

Tags: c++, process

I'm trying to get the process to set it's affinity using the below program.
But i want to set the affinity of chrome or any other process.
How to do that?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void main(){


    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    DWORD_PTR processAffinityMask = 8;

    BOOL success = SetProcessAffinityMask(process, processAffinityMask);
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

    cout << success << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Look at `OpenProcess()`. `SetProcessAffinityMask()` requires a process handle that is open with `PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION` rights. Use `EnumProcesses()` or `Process32First()`/`Process32Next()` to enumerate processes until you find the one you want. Or, if the process's window is visible, you can use `EnumWindows()` or `FindWindow/Ex()` with `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`

Comment: can you edit the above code to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the process ID of an arbitrarily-named process you can do:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int getPID(const std::string& process_name)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (!Process32First(snapshot, &entry)) return 0;

    do
    {
        if (strcmp(entry.szExeFile, process_name.c_str()) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(snapshot);
            return entry.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry));

    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

You can then obtain a handle to that process as follows:

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess (PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
```

And finally you can pass `hProcess` to `SetProcessAffinityMask` and `SetPriorityClass` in the usual way.

I believe you need to be running elevated (i.e. as Administrator) for this to work - and do test that `OpenProcess` succeeded and report the result of calling `GetLastError` if not.